# Helm manifest differs from kubectl manifest after deploying

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I want to update the manifest of an existing deployment in k8s using Helm3, because the APIs were deprecated and I wanted to replace them before upgrading k8s. I thought this would be as simple as changing the `apiVersion` line and upgrade the deployment, but it seems like it's not updating.

When I run the command, it returns success:

```bash
$ helm3 upgrade --install "my-chart" ../charts/my-chart --atomic
Release "my-chart" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
```

What's weird is:

1. Calling `helm3 get manifest my-chart` returns the updated manifest.
2. However, when I call `kubectl get ingress my-chart -o yaml`, it seems to return the **previous version** of the manifest, with the `apiVersion` unchanged.

How is this possible?

Comment: Run `helm template` command on your chart and make sure it has the ingress resource you're looking for; also make sure the existing ingress resource was installed as a part of helm chart and not outside of it.